# RecyclerView not shown

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I used techniques given in other answers like downgrading the versions of dependencies to 24... and 25.0.1.Did not work.I have width and height of RecyclerView as match_parent.
Following is the code.I am using RecyclerView for post title and post description in a blog app:

```
package com.awani.pocketblog;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;  
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mBlogList;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBlogList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.blog_list);
    mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>( Blog.class,
            R.layout.blog_row,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());//model means Blog class over here
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());

        }
    };

    mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

//holder for the recyclerView
public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;

    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){

        TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        post_title.setText(title);

    }

    public void setDesc(String desc){

        TextView post_description = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_description);
        post_description.setText(desc);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_add){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,PostActivity.class));
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

log cat statement which might be causing this..

```
07-08 17:22:10.761 23308-23308/com.awani.pocketblog W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

this is activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.awani.pocketblog.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/blog_list">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

My android studio version is 2.3.2 and he dependencies are 25.3.1
and firebase dependencies are 10.0.1
firebase ui dependency 1.1.1

Comment: add your `activity_main` code

Comment: have you checked to see whether data is actually coming in and can you put a log statement in the populateViewHolder call to see if its being called or not.

Comment: @JudeFernandes the data is being stored,I have checked that.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. I am using this code to print saved news 
You can check this out for reference 
Although I used fragment you can change your code accordingly for Activity.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.example.student.newsapp.R;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class show extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference myRef;
FirebaseAuth firebaseauth;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<show_items, ShowDataViewHolder> mFirebaseAdapter;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public show() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rvforbookmarks);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
    progressDialog.show();



    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Bookmarks");

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    firebaseauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final String userid =firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    // myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("User_Details");
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User_Details").child(userid);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(show.this));

}


//View Holder For Recycler View
public static class ShowDataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView image_title  ;
    private final ImageView image_url;
    private TextView imge_des;
    private ImageView btn_delete;
    private TextView nobookmark;




    public ShowDataViewHolder(final View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        image_url = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fetch_image);
        image_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fetch_image_title);
        imge_des = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fetch_description);
        btn_delete = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        nobookmark = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nobookmark);

    }

    private void Image_Title(String title)
    {
        image_title.setText(title);
    }



    private void Image_URL(String title)
    {
        // image_url.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
        Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                .load(title)
                .crossFade()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                .thumbnail(0.1f)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(image_url);
    }


    public void Image_Des(String title) {
        imge_des.setText(title);

    }
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();




    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<show_items, ShowDataViewHolder>(show_items.class, R.layout.showbookamrks, ShowDataViewHolder.class, myRef) {
        public void populateViewHolder(final ShowDataViewHolder viewHolder, show_items model, final int position) {
            viewHolder.Image_URL(model.getImage_URL());
            viewHolder.Image_Title(model.getImage_Title());
            viewHolder.Image_Des(model.getImage_des());



            //OnClick Item
            viewHolder.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(show.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Do you want to Delete this data ?").setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    int selectedItems = position;
                                    mFirebaseAdapter.getRef(selectedItems).removeValue();
                                    mFirebaseAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(selectedItems);
                                    recyclerView.invalidate();
                                    onStart();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.setTitle("Confirm");
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });

                progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    };


    recyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);

}



}
```

Hope it helps 
Thankyou

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I checked in my code using this as reference but I could not find any mistake :(

Comment: Please post whatever comes in android monitor when you click to show recycler view @RamK

Comment: there are no such errors.the only line I found like error is has been posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow This Example Step by Step

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewClickListener {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_area_list);
       recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);

                    populateRecyclerView();
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(AreaListActivity.this,3);
                    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(AreaListActivity.this, layoutManager.getOrientation());
                    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
     //   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
     //   recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(5);




    }

    public void populateRecyclerView(){
        //pass the allAreaList to it
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter=new RecyclerViewAdapter(AreaListActivity.this,ArrayList,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,this));
    }


    @Override
    public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v, int position) {
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

        myIntent.putExtra("position",position);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    }


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent myIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    finish();
}
}
```

RecyclerViewHolder Class

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

```
//view holder is for girdview as we used in the listView
public ImageView imageView,imageView2;
public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    this.imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
}
```

}

Adapter Class
public class RecyclerView_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
//RecyclerView will extend to recayclerview Adapter
private ArrayList<ModelClass> arrayList;
private Context context;
private static RecyclerViewClickListener itemListener;
//constructor of the RecyclerView Adapter
RecyclerView_Adapter(Context context,ArrayList<ModelClass> arrayList,RecyclerViewClickListener itemListener){
    this.context=context;
    this.arrayList=arrayList;
    this.itemListener=itemListener;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //this method will inflate the custom layout and return as viewHolder
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    ViewGroup mainGroup=(ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item,parent,false);
    RecyclerViewHolder listHolder=new RecyclerViewHolder(mainGroup);

    return listHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final ModelClass modelClass=arrayList.get(position);
    //holder
    RecyclerViewHolder mainHolder=(RecyclerViewHolder)holder;
    //convert the drawable image into bitmap
    Bitmap image= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),modelClass.getImage());
    //set the image into imageView
    mainHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    //to handle on click event when clicked on the recyclerview item and
    // get it through the RecyclerViewHolder class we have defined the views there
    mainHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //get the position of the image which is clicked
         itemListener.recyclerViewListClicked(v,position);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null!=arrayList?arrayList.size():0);
}
```

}

Interface

public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {

```
//this is method to handle the event when clicked on the image in Recyclerview
public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v,int position);
```

}

//and to call this method in activity
RecyclerView_Adapter adapter=new RecyclerView_Adapter(Wallpaper.this,arrayList,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

```
@Override
public void  recyclerViewListClicked(View v,int position){

    imageView.setImageResource(wallpaperImages[position]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code...but I would be glad to know the exact mistake in my code :)